# Midnigh Commander rendering fail in CygWin, Windows 8 and ConEmu (or Console)

Tags: windows-8, terminal, cygwin, conemu, console2

I am trying to use alternate terminal emulator for CygWin in Windows 8.1 x64. I am trying to use [ConEmu] and [Console], but both of them fails in rendering of `mc` program.

[image: Midnight Commander]

Is it fixable?

Comment: Unfortunally I can not attach more than 1 link to post, so ConEmu screen is here: http://i.imgur.com/RpgaEzs.png

Comment: I just found out that setting `TERM=linux` might help, provided that you already have `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8`, — that way both national characters and graphic symbols are drawn, unlike when `TERM=cygwin`.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to your LANG setting solved it for me. I got:

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Starting mc with `LANG=C mc` fixed it for me. You might want to set this into your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Comment: It doesn't work(

Comment: It's been some time. Conemu might have changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your mc/cygwin installation is broken. The origin of the problem is the fact "mc is trying to write utf-8 to console". But it hasn't properly prepared it.

The problem don't relate to ConEmu or Console2. If you run mc from Win+R you will get the same result. Check your cygwin/mc configs, refer to their manuals or contact with their developers.

BTW, I have no problems with mc in my trst box. So I can't say what is wrong in your settings. It will be interesting to get information about it if you solve the problem.

Comment: Inside standard Cygwon terminal emulator, `mintty`, everything works good. Locale settings are completely equals, `ru_RU.UTF-8`. Could you help me with debug it?

Comment: mintty works completely different than expected in Windows. [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinMsys). So you can't compare mintty with ConEmu. The only valid comparison will be, as I've said before, with mc started from Win+R.